# getRange and setRange not pasting properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using GAS to track my pay. Each week, I need to copy a 1X3 array from sheet A in folder A to the last row of sheet B in folder B to create a "timeline". I pulled from code in the answer to a similar question on SO. Here's the code I'm using:

```
 // source spreadsheet
 var srcSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

 // destination spreadsheet
 var payDestSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10kFR2EPO4R--------------------');
 var payDestSheet = payDestSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; // This is the first sheet

 // get the contents of a range in srcSheet
 var range = srcSheet.getRange(212,3,1,3); // This is the range C212:E212
 var values = range.getValues();

 // place the value(s) in the last row of the destination sheet
 var lastRow = payDestSheet.getLastRow();
 payDestSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,3).setValue(values);
```

I'm making a simple, yet fundamental "noob" mistake. The script is reflecting that because only the first value (only cell C212, instead of the 3-cell range of C212:E212) is getting pasted to the destination sheet. I think that I've stared at this too long, because it all isn't making sense any more.

Anyone care to please (gently) put me back on track?

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to: `payDestSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,3).setValues(values);`

Comment: Apparently, it seems that I am now defined by the letter "s". Cooper, thank you for your help. (Didn't I say something about "a noob question"? I'll add your suggestion to my script tomorrow, but for now, thank you.